# Select date from between two timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am facing the following problem.
I have a database with a table which saves Dates (with its time).

Now I would like to know all the tables information where the date is in between two timestamps, but I am getting the following error:
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string".

What I did so far is this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ARBEITSBLOCK WHERE STARTZEIT BETWEEN '30.11.2015 19:00:00' 
                                              and  '01.12.2015 19:05:00';
```

And this which doesn't give me any result but there should be:

```
SELECT * FROM ARBEITSBLOCK 
WHERE TO_CHAR(STARTZEIT,'DD.MM.YYYY H24:MM:SS') BETWEEN '30.11.2015 13:00:00' 
                                                    and '01.12.2015 19:05:00';
```

Comment: What is the data type of `arbeitsblock`?  Please show sample data.  Also, you can use ISO standard date formats in Oracle by using `TIMESTAMP '2015-11-30 19:00:00'.  I would recommend this.

Comment: Arbeitsblock is the table's name and "Startzeit" is the date.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this statement (using Oracle syntax)

```
SELECT *
FROM   ARBEITSBLOCK 
WHERE  STARTZEIT BETWEEN TO_DATE ('12/04/2015 09:00:00 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')
                     AND TO_DATE ('12/04/2015 10:00:00 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM');
```

Comment: your query runs well. but try to explain it preethi

Answer (score 1):

If STARTZEIT is a DATE column, then why are you trying to compare it to a string?

By doing that, you are relying on Oracle being able to say "aha! This string is really a date, so I will attempt to convert it for you!". That's all well and good, but how will Oracle know how the date-in-the-string is formatted?

Well, there's the nls_date_format parameter which is defaulted to 'DD-MON-RR', and I think you can now see why you're getting the "date format picture ends before converting entire input string" error, since 'DD-MON-RR' is a lot shorter than '30.11.2015 19:00:00'.

Instead of relying on this implicit conversion and the bugs that go right along with that (as you've discovered!), you should explicitly convert the string into a date, which you can easily do with the `to_date()` function.

E.g.:

```
select *
FROM   ARBEITSBLOCK
WHERE STARTZEIT BETWEEN to_date('30.11.2015 19:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                and to_date('01.12.2015 19:05:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not **store dates** in the **format** you see. It stores it internally in `7 bytes` with each byte storing different components of the datetime value.

You must use **TO_DATE** with proper **FORMAT MODEL** to explicitly convert the literal to **DATE**.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ARBEITSBLOCK 
WHERE  STARTZEIT BETWEEN 
      TO_DATE('30.11.2015 19:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND 
      TO_DATE('01.12.2015 19:05:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Remember, the `DATE` **data type** has both date and time elements, **TIMESTAMP** is an **extension** to `DATE` **data type**.